# Calculate database size based on date and time

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, oracle

I would like to calculate database size but based on date. e.g. is it possible to know what was the size of my database last month or last year.

```
SELECT table_schema "Data Base Name", sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 1024 /1024 "Data Base Size in GB" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema ;
```

I used this query but it gives only size at the moment. but I want to get historical size so that i can make some analysis on size of database.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't **think** you can use system objects to find this information. One way of identifying space usage is to look at the backup sizes over time. The difference between the backup sizes should reflect the growth of the database.

Maybe this will help you: [Database size growth as a list](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/f1df9f50-9cd9-4c75-a8d9-e2faba6b8574)

Answer (score 0):

If you have backups.

you can get the DB size from your old backups.I think we don't have other way.